# Get <script> in head HTML using DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, domparser

I'm currently using DOM Parser for my project. Also, I'm using CURL in php to scraping the website. I want to get a value from the script tag in the head of the HTML I get. But I really confused how to do that. If run the code bellow :

```
$data_dom = new simple_html_dom();
$data_dom->load($html);

foreach($data_dom->find('script') as $script){
    echo $script->plaintext."<br>";
}
```

The result was the empty value, when I inspect it, only br tag appear. I want to get everything that using script tag. Here is the head value :

```
<head>
I will give you the script I want to get
.....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var keysearch = {"departureLabel":"Surabaya (SUB : Juanda) Jawa Timur Indonesia","arrivalLabel":"Palangkaraya (PKY : Tjilik Riwut | Panarung) Kalimantan Tengah Indonesia","adultNum":"1","childNum":"0","infantNum":"0","departure":"SUB","arrival":"PKY","departDate":"20181115","roundTrip":0,"cabinType":-1,"departureCode":"ID-Surabaya-SUB","arrivalCode":"ID-Palangkaraya-PKY"};

    (function(window, _gtm, keysearch){

        if (window.gtmInstance){
            var departureExp = keysearch.departureCode.split("-");
            var arrivalExp = keysearch.arrivalCode.split("-");

            gtmInstance.setFlightData({
                'ITEM_TYPE': 'flight',
                'FLY_OUTB_CODE': departureExp[2],
                'FLY_OUTB_CITY': departureExp[1],
                'FLY_OUTB_COUNTRYCODE': departureExp[0],
                'FLY_OUTB_DATE': keysearch.departDate,

                'FLY_INB_CODE': arrivalExp[2],
                'FLY_INB_CITY': arrivalExp[1],
                'FLY_INB_COUNTRYCODE': arrivalExp[0],
                'FLY_INB_DATE': keysearch.returnDate,
                'FLY_NBPAX_ADL': keysearch.adultNum,
                'FLY_NBPAX_CHL': keysearch.childNum,
                'FLY_NBPAX_INF': keysearch.infantNum,
            });

            gtmInstance.pushFlightSearchEvent();
        }
    }(window, gtmInstance, keysearch));


                var key = "rkey=10fe7b6fd1f7fa1ef0f4fa538f917811dbc7f4628a791ba69962f2ed305fb72d061b67737afd843aaaeeee946f1442bb";
            var staticRoot = 'http://sta.nusatrip.net';

    $(function() {
        $("#currencySelector").nusaCurrencyOptions({
            selected: getCookie("curCode"),
        });                        
    });
</script>   
</head>
```

I want to get the key variable. I will use it to get the data from the website. Thanks

Comment: And what exactly does not work with the DOM approach?

Comment: I just don't know how to get the script tag value. It's like hidden

Comment: `$data_dom->find('head')` — If you want data in `<script>` then you should try to find a *script* rather than a *head*!

Comment: I have tried it, but it just giving the empty result

Comment: which dom parser are you using?

Comment: php simple html dom parser

Comment: That can't get script content. It just throws it away.

Comment: Then what's your solution?

Comment: PHP doesn't really have a decent DOM parser, I'd use Node.js and jsdom probably

Comment: You can take a look at [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51987159/487813) for a possible workaround

Comment: You could just search for a line starting with `var key = "rkey=`

Comment: @apokryfos I'll try it, thanks for the response. I still want to choose between the python or php actually. Node wasn't my option at all, never learn it before

Comment: @kerbholz how do I get that, when I run my code it result empty?

Comment: @apokryfos _"PHP doesn't really have a decent DOM parser"_ <- you're kidding, right? http://php.net/manual/book.dom.php

Comment: @Phil [it can't handle script contents properly](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d2d01f9bcda5b39e7350e6e138446ee0e7ef258)  and this is what OP actually wants. Wrapping scripts in `CDATA` doesn't work either but that's what CDATA is there for. So, not what I would consider a "decent parser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the rest of the markup looks like, you may be able to just use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), then parse out the value of the var with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). This example will echo the key.

```
<?php

$html = <<<END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var keysearch = {"departureLabel":"Surabaya (SUB : Juanda) Jawa Timur Indonesia","arrivalLabel":"Palangkaraya (PKY : Tjilik Riwut | Panarung) Kalimantan Tengah Indonesia","adultNum":"1","childNum":"0","infantNum":"0","departure":"SUB","arrival":"PKY","departDate":"20181115","roundTrip":0,"cabinType":-1,"departureCode":"ID-Surabaya-SUB","arrivalCode":"ID-Palangkaraya-PKY"};

        (function(window, _gtm, keysearch){

            if (window.gtmInstance){
                var departureExp = keysearch.departureCode.split("-");
                var arrivalExp = keysearch.arrivalCode.split("-");

                gtmInstance.setFlightData({
                    'ITEM_TYPE': 'flight',
                    'FLY_OUTB_CODE': departureExp[2],
                    'FLY_OUTB_CITY': departureExp[1],
                    'FLY_OUTB_COUNTRYCODE': departureExp[0],
                    'FLY_OUTB_DATE': keysearch.departDate,

                    'FLY_INB_CODE': arrivalExp[2],
                    'FLY_INB_CITY': arrivalExp[1],
                    'FLY_INB_COUNTRYCODE': arrivalExp[0],
                    'FLY_INB_DATE': keysearch.returnDate,
                    'FLY_NBPAX_ADL': keysearch.adultNum,
                    'FLY_NBPAX_CHL': keysearch.childNum,
                    'FLY_NBPAX_INF': keysearch.infantNum,
                });

                gtmInstance.pushFlightSearchEvent();
            }
        }(window, gtmInstance, keysearch));


                    var key = "rkey=10fe7b6fd1f7fa1ef0f4fa538f917811dbc7f4628a791ba69962f2ed305fb72d061b67737afd843aaaeeee946f1442bb";
                var staticRoot = 'http://sta.nusatrip.net';

        $(function() {
            $("#currencySelector").nusaCurrencyOptions({
                selected: getCookie("curCode"),
            });                        
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>foo</body>
</html>
END;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//script');

foreach($result as $currScriptTag)
{
    $currScriptContent = $currScriptTag->nodeValue;

    $matchFound = preg_match('/var key = "(.*)"/', $currScriptContent, $matches);

    if($matchFound)
    {
        /*
         * $matches[0] will contain the whole line like var key = "..." 
         * $matches[1] just contains the value of the var
         */
        $key = $matches[1];

        echo $key.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, it's work. Thanks a lot, still don't know about XPath. Do u have any suggest where should I learn it? Thanks @Rob Ruchte

Comment: XPath is very mature and widely used, so there is a lot of material out there, but I use this often, it's one of the most concise references I've found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks again, you really help me